# Isolate the styles in TinyMCE?

Tags: css, tinymce, stylesheet

Hi is there a way that the content entered via TinyMCE isn't affected by the site's css? I want it that way because I want to display the content exactly as the user has entered in the editor. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to do something like this in the past and it is difficult without writing a load of style rules. You could try putting the textarea in an iframe